# Can I install JDK to my flash-memory

Tags: java

I downloaded Eclipse and send it to my flash, and I don't know, how (if it possible) to install JDK on flash. I must just download jdk and install it on flash?
I want to launch my eclipse on every computer I have.

Comment: consider making a Linux USB drive

Comment: Well not good practice but ya can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well according to me  its not at all good practice to do  but here u can have your ans.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/42544-putting-java-on-your-flash-drive/

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes because all time there will be change in variable. or if that wont present flash drive that time eclipse will not start and if u have less memory flash drive it will give very low space for heap. this is what i think i would happy to have suggestion if m may be wrong.

Comment: you can get flash drives that are 64GB or bigger in size

Comment: but not more then hard disk na there will be limitation of course.

Comment: @IGOT i am happy that is helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. Note, you'll want to modify the file `eclipse.ini` and set a `-vm`

Comment: I have started to download jdk for Windows 64-bit. Can I hope, that I can launch it after on another OS? :)

Comment: If you are wanting to run on any computer then you may be better of with a 32 bit JVM

Comment: @IGOT You can hope, but sadly your hope is in vain. Or, to paraphrase Ford; you can run Windows 64-bit Java on any OS you like as long as it's 64-bit Windows.